# LIRC problem after update/upgrade

Tags: lirc

I need to update/upgrade my RPi4 so that I can boot from a SSD.

After `sudo apt-get update` I get a message about the Buster repositories now being marked as 'oldstable'.

Used `sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change` and got everything up to date but now my LIRC is not working correctly.

The IR sensor appears to be detected OK and if I use `irw` and press keys on my remote it does actually display the correct names from my ```lircd.conf' file.

However the commands listed in my `.lircrc` file do not run.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how to debug/resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the update/upgrade reset the file `/lib/systemd/system/irexec.service`

The location of the `lircrc` file had changed to

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/irexec /etc/lirc/irexec.lircrc
```

(used to be in home directory)

and the user which had previously been set to

```
[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
```

had been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the `lirc` package is correctly updated, including all dependencies (see `apt-cache depends lirc`). Then check if `lircd.service` is running and not reporting any errors (`systemctl status lircd`).

Comment: I think the problem is that the location of the lircrc file has been changed, but still investigating...